# wp_editor content doesn't show in theme option

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

I try to insert wp_editor. Everything is fine but the content doesn't show up after save content.

```
function display_slogan_element() {
    $editor_id = "home_slogan";
    $editor_class = "slogan";
    $textarea_name = "slogan";
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slogan', true);
    $settings = array('teeny'=> TRUE);

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );

}
```

I'm not sure what is the problem. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please define `global $post;` after check it?

For example :

```
function display_slogan_element() {
    global $post;
    $editor_id = "home_slogan";
    $editor_class = "slogan";
    $textarea_name = "slogan";
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slogan', true);
    $settings = array('teeny'=> TRUE);

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );

}
```